# How to change ExpansionTile title when it expands?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is there any way to change the title when the expansion tile is expanded? I need to  display "More" with down arrow when it isn't expanded and "less" with up arrow when the expansion tile is expanded.

Comment: Use `onExpansionChanged`

Answer (score 1):

Use onExpansionChanged..

```
bool showMore=true;
ExpansionTile(
    title: Text(showMore?'more':'less,',style:TextStyle(color:Colors.white)),
    onExpansionChanged: (val)=>setState(()=>showMore=!val),
  );
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle your logic in `onExpansionChanged` callback.

```dart
String _title = 'More';

ExpansionTile(
  title: Text(_title),
  onExpansionChanged: (expanded) => setState(() => _title = expanded ? 'Less' : 'More'),
  children: List<Widget>.generate(5, (i) => ListTile(title: Text('Item ${i + 1}'))).toList(),
)
```

Comment: Your welcome, and don't forget to mark the answer accepted :)